# Is 呆 just a casual description or a medically-related thing

Tags: vocabulary

I'm not too sure about 呆. If you say 这个孩子有一点儿呆， does that translate as this child is a bit stupid (just slightly offensive opinion, like 笨), or is it more like 'this child has a learning difficulty' (medical condition)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[呆](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1535/)  mean "dumb" or "stupefied".

"呆" in "这个孩子有一点儿呆" modifies a noun, therefore, it is an adjective for "dumb" or "silly"

"this child has a learning difficulty" means  "这个孩子有一点学习障碍" which is a medical term for such condition

Example of 呆 as "dumb": "呆子" (dumb person); "呆頭呆腦" (dumb looking)

Example of 呆 as "stupefied": 呆了一呆 (stupefied for a moment)

Answer (score -1):

I think the first slightly stupid.

not learning difficulty.

Comment: Please make sure you read the question.